# Intercept WCF Method Call and "Re-route" based on Authentication status

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, intercept

Was curious if there was a way to check if a user is authenticated before making a method call and then returning a custom object and not completing the call if they aren't.  For example:

We set the user principal in the Application_PostAuthenticateRequest in the global.asax to the user making the request if they are authenticated or to an anonymous user if they aren't.  Currently in all methods that require authentication we have something similar to the following code:

`public Result GetSomeObject()`
`{`
        
`if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)`
        
`{`
        
`}`
`}`

Bottom line:  We want to be able to check IsAuthenticated BEFORE we let WCF get inside the method on methods that require authentication, and if true, continue, if not, return a Result object (JSON) with an authentication error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to develop is called ServiceAuthorizationManager in WCF. You can find more information about this on:

http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/implementing-restricted-access-to-a-wcf-service-with-the-serviceauthorizationmanager/

Comment: This is the route I've currently gone with and seems to be working well.  The only issue I have with it is that it returns a bool.  I implemented a custom handler that get's fired if I throw an authentication exception in here or it returns false, however, it seems as though something internal to WCF overwrites my code.  I can see it fire and return a JSON object (in the handler) but WCF ultimately returns an XML object after it leaves the handler.  Anyway of getting around that in ServiceAuthorizationManager?

Comment: Hello, you should check the ServiceSecurityContext in the BeforeCall of the ParameterInspector and throw a WebFaultException if you don't want the request to proceed. The WebFaultException allows you to specify a payload to send to the client. You can find more information on: http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/wcf-rest-tip-2-webfaultexception/

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom httpmodule to intercept the requests to the service layer and do the authentication in there.

Comment: Happen to have any links or could point me to a rough example of some kind?

Comment: here you go. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/07/19/odata-and-authentication-part-5-custom-httpmodules.aspx

Comment: are you hosting the app in IIS or is it self hosted? if it is self-hosted, httpmodules won't work.